# moment.js isAfter giving me an odd result

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Given a time that is less than a day in the past, just earlier this afternoon compared to right now, I'd expect a false value. Instead, I am getting a true.

```
var time = '2018-07-12T04:00:00.000Z';
moment().isAfter(moment.utc(time), 'day'); //returns true
moment().isAfter(time, 'day'); //returns true
```

**Keep in mind, that as of this writing, moment() is:**

```
d:Thu Jul 12 2018 19:21:48 GMT-0700 (PDT) {}
_isAMomentObject:true
_isUTC:false
_isValid:true
```

SINCE moment() is NOT 1 day after my `var time`, why is it returning true. I'd expect false.

Comment: It seems timezone issue. Your moment is returning you GMT-0700 and your `var time` is return GMT+0000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are not comparing in same time frame.

Correct way is `moment.utc().isAfter(moment.utc(time), 'day')`

However, after that, you still can't get the effect you want.

Why?

This is because the 2nd arg in `Moment.isAfter` is precision as state in document:

> As the second parameter determines the precision...

It means, when you do `isAfter('day')` comparison, moment **approximates** the time into 'day', so `'2018-07-12T04:00:00.000Z'` becomes `'2018-07-12'`.

Thus, July 12 is not after July 12.

So if you compare '2018-07-12T23:59:59.000Z' with '2018-07-13T00:00:00.000Z'

like

```
var time = '2018-07-12T23:59:59.000Z';
var time2 = '2018-07-13T00:00:00.000Z';
console.log(moment.utc(time2).isAfter(moment.utc(time), 'day'));
```

It still returns you true.

So to compare time in precise way, use `moment.diff`.

Answer (score 1):

So, here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HardikShah/rLjQx/82546/)

Convert both to `utc` and then compare:

```
var time = '2018-07-12T04:00:00.000Z';
var momentObj = moment(new Date(2018,06,12, 19, 24, 48)).zone("-07:00");
moment.utc(momentObj).isAfter(moment.utc(time), 'day'); // returns false
```

It seems timezone issue. Your `moment()` is returning you `GMT-0700` and your var time is return `GMT+0000`.